# Modifying linked tables access

Tags: vba

I have read that linked tables cannot be modified in access.

I have a back end database and would like to modify the values of these tables.

If I can't do this then access will quickly run out of memory.

Any help would be appreciated as a google yielded nothing significant

Comment: What do you mean by modify 'values' - what values? Do you mean properties? Tables in a backend can be modified with code in frontend but how will that help you conserve memory? Why not just open the backend and make changes directly? How will those changes impact design in the frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you link a table in Access (assuming you do not create a read-only link), you can perform SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements as the backend database granted them to the user that was used for the database link.

You can, however, not change a linked table *itself* (that is, the object in Access, not in the backend database) after it was created. At least there is no trivial way to do so.

Comment: When ever I use an update statement I get an error saying the type of operation is not supported on linked tables

Comment: You should probably have written that in your question, along with the specifics of the table link (which backend database, what driver, which connection string). But that will be another question, more along the lines of "*Why can't I update a table using this specific database link*" instead of "*How, in general, can I update data using a database link*", which this question is all about.